# TA/Pattern algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I have been building a momentum pattern detection algo (essentially involves fitting curves in overlapping windows at different timeframes) and wanted to see if anyone has done/seen similar work. I was specifically looking into intraday movements (not HFT) and don't know if I will end up doing a glorified Roscher test - but would appreciate any feeback/pointers in right direction. I have spent couple of years in various areas including TA to market pschology mumbo jumbo. I feel like I need to shake up and redirect myself.

Comment: Is there a question here?  I would be fairly sure that someone else has fit curves to different timeframes...maybe a better question would be who hasn't done that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's still unclear what the question is.